# Looking for syntax error in js code a vendor sent me to use

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am a designer and am producing an html5 banner for my client using Edge. The adserver they are using requests that this simple javascript be inserted into the html to pass some tracking info. But Dreamweaver says there is a syntax error whenever i add the js. Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickTAG = "<!mpvc/>http://<!mpck/>";
document.location = clickTAG;
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what the syntax error is? Thank you!

Comment: You can also run this through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) to tell you if it is correct or not. There is a syntax error with the semicolon. Which Xymostech provided an answer for below.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like that those semicolons aren't real semicolons, they're [Greek Question Marks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/037e/index.htm) (hex `0x037e`). Change them to normal semicolons, and it should run fine.

```
var clickTAG = "<!mpvc/>http://<!mpck/>";
document.location = clickTAG;
```